# Wordpress Illegal string offset warning after PHP upgrade

Tags: php, wordpress

After moving a wordpress installation from development to the live host illegal string offset warnings have started to appear.  The offending code relates to a custom forms plugin function shown below:

```
function __construct( $data='', $args='' ) {
    if( is_array($args) ) extract($args);

    // Show start & end tags
    $this->formtags = true;

    // Echo the form
    $this->echo = true;

    // Use Ajax
    $this->ajax = true;

    // Show ":" in labels
    if( !$colon ) $this->colon = $colon;
    else $this->colon = true;

    // Process as collection of "p" elements
    $this->class_mode = 'p'; // 'p', 'input'

    // Set path for our transformations
    $this->path = $path ? $path : dirname(__FILE__);

    // Sanitize & assign data & xsl
    if( !$data ) $data = 'contact';
    $this->set( $data );

    //Set Wrapper tag
    if( $args['wrapper_tag'] ) $this->wrapper_tag = $args['wrapper_tag'];
    else $this->wrapper_tag = 'p';
}
```

The final if/else statement is causing the problem:

```
if( $args['wrapper_tag'] ) $this->wrapper_tag = $args['wrapper_tag'];
        else $this->wrapper_tag = 'p';
```

Comment: You should atleast mark the line where this happens and the calling context out here. For now we can only assume that `$args` is not given an array but remains to have it's default value. Which ultimativly triggers the error message in the forlast line,

Comment: Hi Rangad, have updated to include the affected statement. From reading elsewhere I gathered that may be the case regarding $args.  I've tried setting args to a blank array etc but think my syntax may have been incorrect.